# Regular expression Range with decimal validation

Tags: regex

I am trying to set the minimal amount that can be donated on a donation form to be $5.00. The field property allows me to validate using a regular expression. The problem with my expression is that it allows users to donate amounts less than $5.00 if they use decimals. eg $1.99 or $2.50 or $3.75. I need help coming up with a regular expression that will restrict users from using decimal points. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Here is what I have ...

```
/([5-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{3}|9[0-8][0-9]{2}|99[0-8][0-9]|999[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{4}|9[0-8][0-9]{3}|99[0-8][0-9]{2}|999[0-8][0-9]|9999[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{5}|9[0-8][0-9]{4}|99[0-8][0-9]{3}|999[0-8][0-9]{2}|9999[0-8][0-9]|99999[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{6}|9[0-8][0-9]{5}|99[0-8][0-9]{4}|999[0-8][0-9]{3}|9999[0-8][0-9]{2}|99999[0-8][0-9]|999999[0-9]|10000000)/
```

Comment: what is your framework

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
^0*([5-9]|[1-9]\d{1,})(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Test link : https://regex101.com/r/p65pXd/4

Explanation:

`^0*` means any number of leading zeros

`[5-9]` is a single number between 5 to 9 (both included)

`[1-9]\d{1,}` is a number greater or equal to 10

Then we put both of the previous regexs into `( | )` to have a 'OR' condition to match one of those

Then we can add `(\.\d{1,2})?`, means "optionally followed by a dot and 1 or 2 numbers."

We can surround this `^` and `$` meaning beginning and end of input.

Comment: The pattern will also match 00.00 or 00.01 or 01.00 or 00

Comment: Thank you so much Vincent. The above solution works for me. Truly appreciated.

Comment: You can shorten `\d{1,}` to `\d+`. Good answer +1